# Auto create related model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am wondering if it's possible to auto create a related model upon creation of the first model.

This is the models

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)


class TeamMember(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

So what I want to do is something like this on the 'Team' model

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)

    @on_new.do_this
        TeamMember.team = self
        TeamMember.user = request.user
        TeamMember.save()
```

I have tried to find any documentation about this. But only found some example about onetoonefields. But nothing about this.

Appreciate any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using forms to create team.

There is no direct way to create the `TeamMember` instance without the current user(via `request`). `request` is available in views only(unless you are using special middleware or third party library to access it), so we can send it form and create the user by overriding the `save` method of the modelform.

So you can try like this:

```
# Override the model form's save method to create related object 

class TeamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(TeamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Team


    def save(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        instance = super(TeamForm, self).save(**kwargs)
        TeamUser.objects.create(team=instance, user=user)
        return instance
```

And use this form in View:

```
# Update get_form_kwargs methods in create view

class TeamCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = TeamForm
    template = 'your_template.html'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kw = super(TeamCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kw['request'] = self.request
        return kw
```

#### Update

(*from comments*)If you have the user FK availble in `Team` then you can use it to create TeamMember by overriding the `save` method. Try like this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # <-- Override
       instance = super(Team, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       TeamMember.objects.create(user=instance.user, team=instance)
       return instance
```

Comment: I thought the user is always reachable in models, since it's automatically stored behind the scens on all creations. Inside the Admin pages I can see history on all posts which shows datetime, user and action. Even if I haven't declared those columns in the models.

Comment: Not actually. In admin site, you can see this because of [LogEntry](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/models.py). But you access request via third party library/middleware like [django-crequest](https://pypi.org/project/django-crequest/)

Comment: So If I would add a 'user' field to model 'Team' with the user who created. Then I would be able to auto create a 'TeamMember' field with that user?

Comment: yes, in that case you can Override the save method  or add post signals of the Team to add related TeamUser.

Comment: @sumpen please see my answer's update section. Hope it helps!!